# evil-mc binding shadowing my binding?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I use the binding `grr` for my own command in `evil` (along with lots of bindings started with `gr` standing for refactor). I recently enabled [evil-mc](https://github.com/gabesoft/evil-mc) and which stopped `grr` from working like it did before. Disabling `evil-mc` mode made `grr` work again.

Is there a way to stop `grr` from shadowing my command without disable `evil-mc`?

## Trying to debug this:

I found the following in `evil-mc.el`

```
(defvar evil-mc-key-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap))
        (keys '(("grm" . evil-mc-make-all-cursors)
                ("gru" . evil-mc-undo-last-added-cursor)
                ("grq" . evil-mc-undo-all-cursors)
                ("grs" . evil-mc-pause-cursors)
                ("grr" . evil-mc-resume-cursors)
                ("grf" . evil-mc-make-and-goto-first-cursor)
                ("grl" . evil-mc-make-and-goto-last-cursor)
                ("grh" . evil-mc-make-cursor-here)
                ("grj" . evil-mc-make-cursor-move-next-line)
                ("grk" . evil-mc-make-cursor-move-prev-line)
                ("M-n" . evil-mc-make-and-goto-next-cursor)
```

I tried running `(define-key evil-mc-key-map "grr" nil)` and disabling and reenabling evil-mc-mode but `grr` still didn't do the right thing.

I also tried `(define-key evil-mc-key-map "g" nil)` and `(define-key evil-mc-key-map "gr" nil)` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Since `evil-mc-key-map` is hard coded, you're going to have to redefine all of the keybindings that clash with the ones you're already using.  You can't unbind just "g" because the map doesn't bind "g" by itself.  So: do what you did with `define-key`, but for "grr" instead.

Comment: @Dan Thanks Dan, ah yes - undefining `grr` was the first thing I tried - but that didn't work so I tried other bindings. I've updated teh question accordingly.